# How to build conditionaPanel on condition of data table entry that was chosen via double click?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I would like to build an app that is made up of several conditionalPanels. The first panel shows a data table when a reactive value is equal to 0. The other two panels show up when the reacitve value is 1. This happens when one double clicks on the data table.

However, I would like to have an additional condition for the last two panels. One of the panels has to show up when a specified boolean column takes `FALSE` for the double clicked row, the other when it is `TRUE`. As I am not familiar with javascript, I am failing here unfortunately.

The code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

set.seed(42)
A <- rep(0, 10)
for (i in seq_len(10)) {
  random_length <- sample(1:10, 1)
  random_letters <- sample(letters, random_length)
  A[i] <- paste0(random_letters, collapse = "")
}
B <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE)
dt <- data.table(A, B)

ui <- fluidPage(
  conditionalPanel(
   condition = "output.doubleClickOutput == 0", 
    dataTableOutput("tableId")
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.doubleClickOutput == 1",
    actionButton("buttonId1",
                 label = "Back 1")
  ), 
    conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.doubleClickOutput == 1",
    actionButton("buttonId2",
                 label = "Back 2")
  ), 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$doubleClickData, {
    doubleClickIndicator$doubleClick <- 1
  })

  observeEvent(input$buttonId1, {
    doubleClickIndicator$doubleClick <- 0
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$buttonId2, {
    doubleClickIndicator$doubleClick <- 0
  })

  output$doubleClickOutput <- reactive({
    doubleClickIndicator$doubleClick
  })
  outputOptions(output,
                name = "doubleClickOutput",
                suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
    doubleClickIndicator <- reactiveValues(doubleClick = 0)
  
    output$tableId <- renderDataTable(
    dt, 
    options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
      targets = 2, 
      render = JS(
        "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
        "  if(type === 'display'){",
        "    return data ? '<input type=\"checkbox\" disabled checked/>' : '<input type=\"checkbox\" disabled/>';", 
        "  }",
        "  return data;",
        "}"
      )
    ))), 
    callback = JS(
      "table.on('dblclick', 'td', ",
      "function() {",
      "var row = table.cell(this).index().row;",
      "Shiny.setInputValue('doubleClickData', {row});",
      "}",
      ");"
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Everything works fine except for:

```
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.doubleClickOutput == 1",
    actionButton("buttonId1",
                 label = "Back 1")
  ), 
    conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.doubleClickOutput == 1",
    actionButton("buttonId2",
                 label = "Back 2")
  ),
```

It should be something like this

```
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.doubleClickOutput == 1 && 
    dt[name='B'].rows(input$doubleClickData) == false",
    actionButton("buttonId1",
                 label = "Back 1")
  ), 
    conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.doubleClickOutput == 1 && 
    dt[name='B'].rows(input$doubleClickData) == true",
    actionButton("buttonId2",
                 label = "Back 2")
  ),
```

but with correct javascript. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand everything, but what about this:

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table) # why do you use data.table?
library(DT)

set.seed(42)
A <- rep(0, 10)
for (i in seq_len(10)) {
  random_length <- sample(1:10, 1)
  random_letters <- sample(letters, random_length)
  A[i] <- paste0(random_letters, collapse = "")
}
B <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE)
dt <- data.table(A, B)

ui <- fluidPage(
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.doubleClickOutput == 0", 
    dataTableOutput("tableId")
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = 
      "output.doubleClickOutput == 1 && input.doubleClickData == false",
    actionButton("buttonId1",
                 label = "Back 1")
  ), 
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = 
      "output.doubleClickOutput == 1 && input.doubleClickData == true",
    actionButton("buttonId2",
                 label = "Back 2")
  ), 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  doubleClickIndicator <- reactiveValues(doubleClick = 0)
  
  observeEvent(input[["doubleClickData"]], {
    doubleClickIndicator[["doubleClick"]] <- 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["buttonId1"]], {
    doubleClickIndicator[["doubleClick"]] <- 0
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["buttonId2"]], {
    doubleClickIndicator[["doubleClick"]] <- 0
  })
  
  output[["doubleClickOutput"]] <- reactive({
    doubleClickIndicator[["doubleClick"]]
  })
  outputOptions(
    output,
    name = "doubleClickOutput",
    suspendWhenHidden = FALSE
  )
  
  output[["tableId"]] <- renderDataTable(
    dt, 
    options = list(
      columnDefs = list(
        list(
          targets = 2, 
          render = JS(
            "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
            "  if(type === 'display'){",
            "    return data ? '<input type=\"checkbox\" disabled checked/>' : '<input type=\"checkbox\" disabled/>';", 
            "  }",
            "  return data;",
            "}"
          )
        )
      )
    ), 
    callback = JS(
      "table.on('dblclick', 'td:nth-child(3)', function() {",
      "  var cell = table.cell(this);",
      "  Shiny.setInputValue('doubleClickData', cell.data(), {priority: 'event'});",
      "});"
    )
  )
  
  observe({ # (test)
    print(input[["doubleClickData"]])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that you have to click a little next to the checkboxes, not on the checkboxes.

---

## EDIT

To get the desired event by clicking anywhere on a row, replace the callback with this one:

```
callback = JS(
  "table.on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {",
  "  var rowIndex = table.row(this).index();",
  "  var bool = table.cell(rowIndex, 2).data();",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('doubleClickData', bool, {priority: 'event'});",
  "});"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That's pretty close to what I would like to have. At the moment one has to click next to the checkboxes. It would be nice if it also worked when one double clicks at any point in the table. I load data.table for the example data.

Comment: @FireSalamander Ah ok. Will show you later, I'm busy now. You don't need `data.table`, an ordinary dataframe is enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realized that I oversimplified my example code. Actually the second and third conditional panel should show content from the table that corresponds to the selected row. For example, when I double click the first row, I should be able to display `e`. When I use two callbacks, the one from my question and the one from your answer, I can achieve this. So your answer solved my problem, thank you very much.